# Postfix cannot load Certification Authority data error

Tags: debian, ssl, postfix, arm

I'm trying to use postfix as gmail relay

smtp parameters are

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN.com/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN.com/cert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt</id_string></id_string>
```

The message appears as correctly sent but actually no mail is delivered and in the mail log the issue seems caused by an error with TSL

```
 cannot load Certification Authority data, CAfile="/etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt": disabling TLS support
 warning: TLS library problem: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt','r'):
 warning: TLS library problem: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
 warning: TLS library problem: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:../crypto/x509/by_file.c:199:
 connect to smtp.gmail.com:25: Network is unreachable
```

The file `ca-certificates.crt` exists in the path `/etc/ssl/` and was already present in Debian distro

Another weird thing is that if in `main.cf` I try to change the line

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt
```

using some other certificate, the error

```
cannot load Certification Authority data, CAfile="/etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt": disabling TLS support
```

remains the same, rather than pointing to the name of the certificate configured, despite used `postfix reload` and `systemctl restart postfix.service` to make sure to update the configuration

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Just a small question to rule out the obvious mistake: Does `/etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt` contain the Let's Encrypt intermediate chain certificate? On my server it is provided in the file `ca.pem` when I request a new ECDSA certificate. The reason I ask is because how else is Gmail going to verify that your certificate is a valid Let's Encrypt certificate if it does not know which intermediate certificate was used?

Answer (score 5):

On my Debian machines (9, 10 and 11) the path to `ca-certificates.crt` is:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

This should be the default, I did not change it.

On my postfix installations I didn't even set the `smtp_tls_CAfile` parameter. If you installed both postfix and the ca-certificates package via the Debian package management it should default to the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Try> chmod 644 ca-certificates.crt
or verify the correct layout for a certificate bundle